# Flutter Dribble clone

Tags: flutter, user-interface

can someone Please help me clone this ui I got it from Dribble and Im facing the problem with the box radius.
I tried using a stack but it doesnt show the container radius maybe i need to use a custom widget.
Please any help is needed i am stuck on this problem.
[image]

```
        Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:Text(DateTimeFormat.format(DateTime.now(),format: 'D M, Y')
          ,style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 26
            ),),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list_outlined),
              tooltip: 'Filter By date',
              onPressed: () {

              },
            ),
          ],
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff405cbf),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Color(0xff405cbf),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.maximize_outlined,size: 70,color: Colors.white60,),
                  )
              ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                    spreadRadius: 1,
                                    blurRadius: 15
                            )
                          ]
                        ),

                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: Text("History of Tips",style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black
                              ),),
                            ),
                            GFCard(
                              color: Colors.white60,
                              boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                              content: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("date"),
                                      SizedBox(width: 150,),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text("Odd"),
                                          Divider(color: Colors.black,),
                                          Text("Status")
                                        ],

                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            )

                          ],

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
          ),

        ),
);
```

[image]

I added in some box shadow and some different colors but still it's not quite right.

Comment: can you include the result image of your code?

Comment: also please add a reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `appbar` inside your body like this:

```
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff405cbf),
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      AppBar(
        title: Text(
          DateTimeFormat.format(DateTime.now(), format: 'D M, Y'),
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list_outlined),
            tooltip: 'Filter By date',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff405cbf),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 100,
                color: Color(0xff405cbf),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.maximize_outlined,
                    size: 70,
                    color: Colors.white60,
                  ),
                )),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 15)
                    ]),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        "History of Tips",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GFCard(
                        color: Colors.white60,
                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                        content: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("date"),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 150,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text("Odd"),
                                    Divider(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    Text("Status")
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: glad to help. was it what you want? @AyoubEnnaoui

Comment: yes pretty much exactly that.But i didnt understand why the appbar is put inside body of scaffold. Cant it be another solution.

Comment: appbar is a widget, you can use it every where that accept widget. @AyoubEnnaoui